# Dojo Error Reporting Strangeness - dojoBuild incorrectly saying 'function is undefined'

Tags: javascript, dojo, undefined, amd, dojo-build

Super weird issue. Basically, everything works fine development mode but when I run it through dojoBuild, a specific modal is sometimes working and sometimes isn't.

When it's not, it says 'undefined' is not a function, insinuating 'define' is undefined. However, when i check to see that 'define' IS defined, i get a function successfuly returned.

Here's the declaration part of the modal in question (it's being used twice on the page):

`1 define([
  2     "dojo",
  3     "dojo/_base/declare",
  4     "dojo/_base/lang",
  5     "myapp/js/utils/globals"
 13 ], function (
 14     dojo,
 15     declare,
 16     lang,
 17     globals
 25 ) {`

Anyone see this before or know of anything that might be going on? Would any more files be helpful?

Here is my [profile](https://gist.github.com/streetlight/9974669) if that helps too.

[image: define is defined, man!]

Comment: Maybe you're calling `define()` before it's actually loaed.

Comment: What's strange though is that this same module is being called from a defined module, and it's being successfully called elsewhere? Is there a way to test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this actually had nothing to do with dojoBuild itself but more to do with the error reporting.

The error was actually inside of the module, but when dojoBuild ran and compressed it, I'm guessing that when it errored, it defaulted the reporting to line 1 of the uncompressed file, which made me believe it was the define function that was undefined when really it was something else.